# Laravel looking for path on my localhost instead of deployed server

Tags: php, laravel

I have Laravel installed on my localhost. And when I try to deploy it to the server, it throws an error: `View [frontend.layouts.login] not found.`

And I can see that it is looking at my local file path when on my machine aka:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/personal/project_name/resources/views
```

Instead of the server's file path.

If I try and copy the project outside of the personal folder (on my local machine), so make the file path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project_name/resources/views
```

It gives the same issue?

Is it something with caching the views?

The other error on the same page is:

```
file_put_contents(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/personal/project_name/storage/framework/sessions/7a0aaa6c977031111312b785c7b7e22a659b6a36): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

And again, the server has nothing to do with my local machine.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might fix it

Go to config/app.php
and change the url to your production url

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue is due to the [Laravel Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching).I suggest you

1. Remove the configuration cache file
2. Flush the application cache
3. Create a cache file for faster configuration loading

To do this, run the following Artisan commands on your command line

1. php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan config:cache

Where you don't have access to the command line on your server, you can [programmatically execute commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) like this:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: It Worked . Thanks . Added in Routes

Comment: Thanks, very usefull!
I've added it to the route and call it manually when want to clear all!

Comment: Wow, happy to know; Zam85 and  @Wal Heredia

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue so i tried many things including all the solutions in this question, but it didn't work.

What worked for me is that i just deleted this file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` and it worked.

Comment: Yes, i guess from 5.7+ that's the only working solution